# A word that describes someone who is obsessed with the concept of love

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I am looking for a word that describes a person who is obsessed with love and romance, not particularly a person, but life and everything it has to offer. Someone who romanticizes everything. I don’t know if romanticist is the word, is it?

Comment: Maybe you want the noun ***romantic***.  E.g. He is a *romantic*.

Comment: @jim Or a _**hopeless romantic**_ if he's really far gone!

Answer (score 0):

It can't be "romanticist" since the definition as given by the SOED is

> "an exponent or admirer of romanticism in literature, art, or music".

There is the verb "**to romanticize**", though, with the following meanings (SOED).

> **1**  *v.t.* make romantic or unrealistic in character; describe or portray in a romantic fashion
> **2** *v.i.* Indulge in romantic thoughts, words or actions

There is then the noun which corresponds to the verb: "**romanticization**" and also  the noun "**romanticizer**", the definition of which is found in the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/romanticizer) with the following definition.

> One who romanticizes

From the meaning of the verb then, a romanticizer can be someone who gives a turn to certain situations so that they appear more romantic than they really are, and someone such as that might be a writer or a film director  or simply someone with an opportunity of some sort to shape his/her own environment and life. That however does not make of this person necessarily  someone who is obsessed with the romantic aspect of life.  Otherwise, it might be someone that goes after what appears romantic, who indulges in it.

To describe the particular sort of romanticizer that romanticizes everything obsessively I'd use a phrase like **romanticizer to excess**.